# How to pass function name to model event callback in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'd like to hook a model event to perform a task after the model has been deleted. I've added the following code to my model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted( 'static::removeStorageAllocation' );
}
```

Rather than put the logic I want to run inside a closure in the boot function, which seems a pretty ugly spot for it, I noticed in the method signature it supposedly takes "\Closure|string  $callback" is there a way I can specify a function name like I've tried to do above? I can't seem to come up with anything that works. I've tried lots of combinations:

```
'self::removeStorageAllocation'
'static::removeStorageAllocation'
'\App\MyModel::removeStorageAllocation'
```

I know I can probably just specify a closure which calls my function, but I'm wondering what the string form of $callback is for?

Comment: if it is a method you may want to add () to end of static::removeStorageAllocation()

Comment: I got the same error: ReflectionException with message 'Class static::removeStorageAllocation() does not exist'
It's as though laravel framework is expecting a class rather than method. Also the function actually has a single parameter being a reference to the model that fired the delete event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just pass an anonymous function:

```
static::deleted(function() {
    static::removeStorageAllocation();
});
```

---

To know the string representation of $callback, you could look at the source of deleted:

```
/**
 * Register a deleted model event with the dispatcher.
 *
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @param  int  $priority
 * @return void
 */
public static function deleted($callback, $priority = 0)
{
    static::registerModelEvent('deleted', $callback, $priority);
}
```

You'll see it is registering an event listener:

```
/**
 * Register a model event with the dispatcher.
 *
 * @param  string  $event
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @param  int  $priority
 * @return void
 */
protected static function registerModelEvent($event, $callback, $priority = 0)
{
    if (isset(static::$dispatcher))
    {
        $name = get_called_class();

        static::$dispatcher->listen("eloquent.{$event}: {$name}", $callback, $priority);
    }
}
```

Therefore, $callback is used eventually as a listener.  A string representation would most likely be the name of a listener class, not a method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I said in the question "I know I can probably just specify a closure which calls my function, but I'm wondering what the string form of $callback is for?"

Comment: Thanks for that, I did try and trace the code but got a little lost, fairly new to php (and laravel). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create a protected or public static function on your model (private will not work):

```
protected static function myStaticCallback($model)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Then add a boot method to your model, using an array for the callback [class, function]:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(['MyModel', 'myStaticCallback']);
}
```